# Find the joint density function of $X_1$ and $X_2$

Tags: probability

Let $X_1$ denote the weight (in tons) of a bulk item stocked by a supplier at the beginning of a week and suppose that $X_1$ has a uniform distribution over the interval $0 \le X_1 \le 1$. Let $X_2$ denote the amount (by weight) of this item sold by the supplier during the week. Given the value $X_1=x_1$, $X_2$ has a uniform distribution over the interval $[0,x_1]$, where $x_1$ is a specific value of $X_1$.

a)Find the joint density function of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

b.If the supplier stocks a half-ton of the item, what is the probability that she sells more than a quarter ton?

c. If it is known that the supplier sold a quarter ton of the item, what is the probability that she had stocked more than a half-ton?

---

Since the two variables are not indepent, I find it hard to say anyting about their joint density function. What I first of all did was find the PDF for $X_1$ which is obviously just 1. For $X_2$ the PDF should be $1/x_1$, I would say. However, how do these help me to find the joint density function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right for c), you need to calculate
$$ P(X_1 > \frac 1 2 \vert X_2 = \frac 1 4).  $$
Ok, you know that $X_2 \vert X_1$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,X_1)$ so
$$ P(X_2 > \frac 1 4 \vert X_1 = \frac 1 2) = P( \mathcal U(0,\frac 1 2) > \frac 1 4) = \int_{1/4}^{1/2} 2 dx = \frac 1 2.  $$
For c), calculate the density of $X_2 \vert X_1$ using Bayes formula and do the same.

Comment: For c, I think Bayes formula gives you f(X1|X2)=f(X1)f(X2|X1)/f(X2) = 1 * (1/x1) / f(X2). However, how do I find f(X2)? Or am I doing something wrong? Thanks a lot again :).

Comment: Could you please help me out on c? I still cant seem to find the correct answer. Integrating 1/x1 over x1 to find f(x2) doesnt give me a finite answer. How should I do this instead? @roger

Answer (score 1):

You know the distribution of $X_2 \vert X_1$ and that of $X_1$ so you can deduce their joint distribution.

Comment: Are you referring to the formula for conditional probabilities? So you mean that P(X1 intersection X2) = P(X2|X1)*P(X1)? Does this work for density functions too? Or is this not what you meant?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. Bayes formula does work for density too

Comment: So would the answer in this case then be 1 * 1/x1 = 1/x1? Or what else would it be? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, on the condition that $0 < x_2 < x_1 < 1$. It's zero otherwise.

Comment: actually it's $1/x_1$ if $0\leq x_2 \leq x_1 \leq 1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Comment: @roger Thanks a lot! I thought it would be easy to do questions b and c if I had done question a, however Im not that sure how to approach these two as well. Could you give me a hint on those too? Which formula do I use for question b? Since there is no x2 left in the one we derived in a, I assume that is not that formula?

Comment: for b), you need to calculate
$$ P(X_2 > \frac 1 4 \vert X_1= \frac 1 2)  $$
for c)
$$ P(X_1 > \frac  1 2 \vert X_2 > \frac 1 4)  $$  
for b), simply use the density of $X_2 \vert X_1$ and for c) use Bayes's formula.

Comment: @roger Sorry Im relatively new to these things. Could you please show me how this is done? And for c I think you misread, since the question states X2=1/4 I think and not X2>1/4. Thanks a lot for your help, its really appreciated.